# Full Path On Physical Drive To Relative Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have directory on my server that stores user profile images.
They're being saved in UserImages directory.

On SQL Server, User's profile image is being saved like this:

```
C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Project\\Project\\UserImages\\userimage.jpg
```

I have a GET `ActionResult` method that uses `ET` to get user data and returns it to View.
The problem however is, I'm lost as to how I can pass a usable relative Path from full path as given above.

**How can I make relative path from absolute path on hard drive so it can be used as src for a HTML image?**

Edit:
`Razor` won't work, since image can be updated using `AJAX` - when it is, I receive some `JSON` from server with new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the backend you can do something like this. Not so fancy, but it can do the job I think.

```
var relativePath = yourPathOnDb.Substring(0, Server.MapPath("~").Length);
```